# How to use process.hrtime.bigint

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I write

```
const a = process.hrtime.bigint();
```

Linting suggests that it is fine, but I see the compilation error

```
error TS2339: Property 'bigint' does not exist on type 'HRTime'.
```

Which seems peculiar when I read the docs
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html
So how can I use bigint() in typescript? My node version is 10.16.2. I am at a loss to understand why typescript doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `BigInt` is at stage 4 and can be readily used in recent browser & Node versions, at the time of writing, you will still need to set your [TS `target` config](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to at least `ES2020` or `ESNext`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext"
        ...
    }
}
```

As for the actual `hrtime.bigint()` issue, you might have to either add/update your `@types/node` type declarations dependency and/or Node itself...

In my [own project](https://thi.ng/bench), I've also used this code below for providing backward compatibility with older Node versions (though w/ obvious lack of precision):

```
/**
 * If available, returns wrapper for `process.hrtime.bigint()` else
 * falls back to `Date.now()`. In all cases, returns a nanosec-scale
 * timestamp, either as `bigint` or `number`.
 */
export const now =
    typeof BigInt !== "undefined"
        ? typeof process !== "undefined" &&
          typeof process.hrtime !== "undefined" &&
          typeof process.hrtime.bigint === "function"
            ? () => process.hrtime.bigint()
            : () => BigInt(Date.now() * 1e6)
        : () => Date.now() * 1e6;
```

Comment: @SlightlyKosumi Great, just updated/fixed the code too (forgot to scale `Date.now()` to nano sec scale). Can you accept the answer too, pls?